# createNativeStackNavigator not longer available in react-navigation site

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

**complete remove native stack navigation link in react-navigation site**

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Previously i am using - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/native-stack-navigator.html.

**Any one know why react-navigation remove native stack navigation?**

Answer (score 1):

Version Changed, and lots of things changed after that.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator

maybe this link is not available after a year so just follow below things.

this is the link for stack navigator and actually is been extracted to individual. and all other navigators also. 
See API Reference in ReactNavigation site.

Comment: createNativeStackNavigator available when 5.0 launch approx 2 month. Suddenly now they hide in site. It's working perfectly and i have implement also. But now not showing in site.

Comment: I mean if it's not there  written that they have to hide it, maybe its breaking and will be up in neartime.

Answer (score -2):

It's in react-native-screens package

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/tree/master/native-stack